# Laravel error. Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I have a relationship between two tables: proposals and supervisors. I am retrieving all proposals and passing them to the view. What I want is to print the name of the person who proposed. Table "Proposals" has a column "Supervisor_ID".

Note: the code was perfectly running a few days ago, but now I have this error.

[image: Laravel Error picture]

Proposal.php

```
public function supervisor(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Supervisor');

}
```

Supervisor.php

```
public function proposals(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Proposal','id', 'supervisor_ID');

}
```

index.blade.php

```
@foreach($proposals as $proposal)
     {{$proposal->supervisor->last_name}}, {{$proposal->supervisor->first_name}}

@endforeach
```

Comment: Update your controller code

Comment: Seems like some proposal doesn't have a supervisor in the database.

Comment: Only one entry in Proposals table, and there is a supervisor id.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not including `supervisor` relation while calling. For this you should add this following line in your `Proposal.php` file

```
 protected $with = ["supervisor"];
```

Comment: If a relation is not eager loaded (either manually by calling `with('relation')` or through the method you described), it will be lazy loaded by the Eloquent framework on the first call. But this only works when the relationship methods are properly set up.

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship definitions are wrong. The `supervisor()` relation might not work because you are using column names that do not follow the Laravel default schema (but as most SQL systems are case-insensitive when it comes to column names, the likelihood of this being an issue is very small). But the `proposals()` relation on the other hand has the parameters in the wrong order, which is an issue for sure. You'll also have to add the additional parameters on the `supervisor()` relation.

After fixing the mentioned issues, you should have something like this:

```
// Proposal.php
public function supervisor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Supervisor::class, 'Supervisor_ID', 'id');
}

// Supervisor.php
public function proposals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Proposal::class, 'Supervisor_ID', 'id');
}
```

Be aware that I also changed `supervisor_ID` to `Supervisor_ID` as written by you. Also note that `Supervisor::class` is a PHP constant for `App\Supervisor` if the class `Supervisor` is in the `App` namespace. Using this kind of notation does not only look cleaner, it also allows for better static code analysis of IDEs and other tools.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the proposed solutions and some showed the same issue. I solved the issue by removing all additional parameters in the model relations. It turns out that the framework automatically performs the relationships if table fields in DB are named accordingly.

Current working code:

```
//Proposal.php
    public function supervisor(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\Supervisor');
    }

//Supervisor.php
public function proposals(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Proposal');   
    }
```

Thank You guys :)